# Launching BAPI programmatically from R?

Tags: r, business-objects, saprfc, bapi

Basically I have 2 questions::

1. What are the differences between BAPI's and InfoQueries in SAP?
2. How would you launch and retrieve the results of BAPI's programmatically from outside of SAP?

I am trying to launch SAP BAPI' via `R`, and I saw that the `RSAP` package should allow [sending InfoQueries](https://rdrr.io/cran/RSAP/man/RSAPExecInfoQuery.html), but how about BAPI's?

I'm quite ignorant about SAP, but InfoQueries seem to be used by Business Warehouse while BAPI's would be linked with BusinessObjects, so I probably won't be able to use this `RSAP` library... Any idea?

Versions:

```
SAP ERP 2005, SP Stack 31
SAP Netweaver 7.5, SP Stack 16
EHP8 for SAP ERP 6.0: SP Stack 13
```

Comment: In the SAP solutions where BAPI are provided, they are linked to what is called "Business Objects", but which are absolutely NOT related to BusinessObjects.

Comment: `they are linked to what is called "Business Objects", but which are absolutely NOT related to BusinessObjects` welcome to the world of SAP, lol

Answer (score 1):

You are quite ignorant about SAP and I'm quite ignorant about R, so let's align.

From what I've learnt about `r` package here and there (because it was [removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSAP/index.html)):

- RFC calls are supported
- keyword for calling an RFC function is a `nRSAPInvoke(con, func, parms)`

Sample coding to retrieve the results of a `RFC_GET_TABLE_ENTRIES` function is listed in the [R docu](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSAP/versions/0.9/topics/RSAPInvoke)

```
con <- RSAPConnect(ashost="nplhost", sysnr="42", client="001", user="developer", passwd="developer", lang="EN", trace="1", lcheck="1")

info = RSAPGetInfo(con) print(info)

parms <- list('BYPASS_BUFFER' = 'X', 'MAX_ENTRIES' = 50, 'TABLE_NAME' = 'T005')

res <- RSAPInvoke(con, "RFC_GET_TABLE_ENTRIES", parms) print(res$ENTRIES) RSAPClose(con)
```

BAPI tabular results are returned as `data.frame`.

The main thing you must know and which is probably gets you confused: `BAPI` and `RFC function` is a **same** thing in your context, so everything you read in the web about RFC calls fits you too.

Also consider this question, it may be quite useful:
[How do I extract non-HANA ECC tables into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050334/how-do-i-extract-non-hana-ecc-tables-into-r/)

What concerns your first question about InfoQueries, please create a new SO question for it, putting two questions into one violates SO rules.
But I assume your new question would be closed too, because questions like "*What is A? What is B? What is the difference between A and B (BAPI and InfoQuery?*" are discouraged on SO.